# Проблема получения значения getIntent().getExtras()

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-bundle

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Создал viewpager2 и в одном из фрагментов не могу принять данные из другого актива.

Кусок кода:

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            userID = bundle.getLong("id");
        }
```

Проблема:

```
Cannot resolve method 'getIntent' in 'Fragment1'
```

Comment: Код добавляйте текстом, а не картинками!

Comment: Если ты не заметил тут не совсем кода а ошибка

Comment: Да в любом случае! То что подсвечивает IDE тоже можно вставить текстом!

Comment: Вот другое дело же. Так вы поможете не только себе, но и другим которые будут искать решение по этой ошибке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `getIntent()` можно вызвать только в активити. Для фрагмента нужно использовать:

```
getActivity().getIntent()
```